# Need a chat: for every users AND for specific users

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I need to build a chat functionaly for work.
Decision was made to use ratchet PHP, and here is what we need:

- **general chatroom:** here, a connected user send a message to all connected users
- **workshop chatroom:** here, a user connected can send a message to all connected users with the same workshopId as the sender.

I started with **general chatroom**.
It's working perfectly: if I send a message, other connected users are receiving it

Here is my code (only relevant parts):

**- chat.html**

```
<script>
    function connect() {

        var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080?token={{ user.user_id }}');

        // OPEN THE CONNECTION
        conn.onopen = function (e) {
            console.log("Connection established!");
        };

        // SEND A MESSAGE
        $(".send_message").click(function() {

            var userId = '{{ user.user_id }}';
            var userName = '{{ user.name }}'+' '+'{{ user.insertion ? user.insertion : '' }}'+' '+'{{ user.surname }}';
            var msg = $(".message_input").val();

            var data = {
                userId: userId,
                userName: userName,
                msg: msg
            };

            conn.send(JSON.stringify(data));

            var messageBlock = '' +
                '<li class="message right">' +
                '<div class="text_wrapper">' +
                '<div class="sending_informations">' + data.userName +'</div>' +
                '<div class="text">' + data.msg + '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</li>';

            // append in .messages >
            $('ul.messages').append( messageBlock );

            // SET THE INPUT EMPTY after sending
            $(".message_input").val("");
        });

        // WHEN A MESSAGE ARRIVE
        conn.onmessage = function(e) {

            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            var messageBlock = '' +
                '<li class="message left">' +
                '<div class="text_wrapper">' +
                '<div class="sending_informations">' + data.userName +'</div>' +
                '<div class="text">' + data.msg + '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</li>';

            // append in .messages >
            $('ul.messages').append( messageBlock );
        };

        conn.onclose = function(e) {
            console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 3 second.', e.reason);
            setTimeout(function() {
                connect();
            }, 1000);
        };

        conn.onerror = function(err){
            console.log('Error' + err);
            conn.close();
        };
    }
    connect();

</script>
```

**- chat.php**

```
/**
 * Class Chat
 * @package Ddis\controller
 */
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    /**
     * @var SplObjectStorageAlias
     */
    protected $clients;

    /** @var array */
    private $channel;

    /** @var array */
    private $users;

    /** @var Connection */
    private $database;

    /**
     * Chat constructor.
     * @param Connection $database
     */
    public function __construct(Connection $database)
    {
        $this->clients          = new SplObjectStorageAlias;
        $this->channel          = [];
        $this->users            = [];
        $this->database         = $database;
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        $querystring = $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();
        parse_str($querystring, $queryarray);

        $this->users[isset($queryarray['token']) && $queryarray['token'] != '' ? $queryarray['token'] : $conn->resourceId] = $conn;

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $from
     * @param $msg
     */
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n", $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        $data = json_decode($msg, true);

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // The connection is closed, remove from connection list
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $conn
     * @param \Exception $e
     */
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Now, I have to start the second part of this project:

**workshop chatroom**

Here is some context: in my database, each user as a field "workshopId".
The idea is: if user X, with workshopID = 1 is sending a message, all the users with workshopID = 1 are gonna receive it, in a another view.

So I tought of having > 2 views:

- chat.html > for the main Chat, you already saw the code just above
- workshopChat.html > for the workshop Chat, with only ONE difference in the code:

var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080?token={{ user.user_id }}&channel={{ user.workshop_id }}');

So for the Chat.php, I need now to be able to check if I have a channel param:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
{
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        $querystring = $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();
        parse_str($querystring, $queryarray);

        print_r($queryarray);
        die("CHANNEL PARAM ?");

        $this->users[isset($queryarray['token']) && $queryarray['token'] != '' ? $queryarray['token'] : $conn->resourceId] = $conn;

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}
```

I can see the param in my print_r().

My question now, is how to deal with this: so if this param exist, how to send only to specific users ?

Comment: _"Is this correct or are you already seeing some issues?"_ - You're the best person to answer that question. Does it work and does it do what you want?

Comment: No, it's not doing what I want. If it was the case I'll not post here ;)

The documentation fro ratchet is pretty simple and I struggle to understand how I can send to specific users.

Comment: Since you asked if it is correct, it's not obvious that it doesn't work. When asking for help, you _must_ include a proper explanation of the issue. What do you expect to happen and what actually happens? You also need to do some debugging to narrow the issue down to where it fails. If you just post your code without any error description, you're basically asking us to read through your code and guess what your issue is, which isn't constructive for anyone. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok, I understand.
What is the best wayt to ask properly ? Change my intial post ?

Comment: Yes, the easiest is to just [edit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63579261/edit).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did my very best to explain better. Hope it's fine now I need help lol